# QMutexLocker not locking QMutex

Tags: c++, qt

QMutexLocker not working when locking the thread.

- Answer:

  ```
  void foo() {
       // QMutexLocker(&mutex); // wrong, it will not just lock and unlock
       QMutexLocker locker(&mutex); // right, it will lock until the 'locker' scope ends
       ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Do you have a question about that? It looks like you understand it already.

Answer (score 2):

Off course this is wrong :

```
QMutexLocker(&mutex);
```

because it creates a temporary mutex, which locks, and unlocks at the end of the statement.

Here :

```
QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
```

you are creating an object of `QMutexLocker` type, named locker, which locks the mutex and unlocks it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: The first is not an error, it's perfectly valid, albeit probably not what's intended: It creates a temporary locker, which will lock the mutex. Problem is, the locker is destroyed again right away at the end of the statement, and the mutex unlocked.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks. I tried something else (because at this PC I have no qt installed) and that failed, I thought the above would fail to compile.